# How to link a local IP Address on Website and make it accessible to users externally

Tags: php, ip, remote-access

I am working on a php project wherein I have to link a module hosted on a local server in the network i.e. 192.168.2.13/OPAC, to my website. The link that is accessible via the mentioned Static IP address on the local network and is accessible when connected to that network. How can I make it accessible externally. Kindly help. Thanks.

Answer (score -1):

Firewall is blocking the connection from other computer, please turn off the firewall and you can access it

Comment: Yes, turn off the entire firewall and let everything in, solid idea. - Also, most likely boggus, most likely a issue of forwarding a port or something, not a firewall blocking.

Comment: Yes the firewall has been disabled and also I have done port forwarding. That is, 192.168.2.13 and 443 has been set as the port number for auth.

Comment: I would like to know how to access this IP Address from web. Is there anything that has to be appended to the mentioned IP address? to indicate that it is pointing at the IP from the connected router?